# How to extract current time in HH:mm format without converting into string in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timespan

I need to get current time in `TimeSpan` data type (not in `string`) in the format `HH:mm` (only hour and minute parameters).
I have written the following code:

```
AdminRequestTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Here the data-type of `AdminRequestTime` is `TimeSpan`. It gives the value `15:52:28.2843710`, but I only want `15:52`.

How do I do this (preferably without using parse)?

Comment: You can create new TimeSpan object and copy values there

Comment: Why would you want the current time as a TimeSpan?

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi I tried doing it. but it didn't work ! Can you please show me how it's done ? Thanks.

Comment: @kaffekopp app requirement man !

Comment: @Shiwa the question isn't clear. Are you trying to *round* the time to the nearest minute, truncate seconds or *format* it as a string that contains minutes?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wanted the current hour and minutes in timespan format. That's all. Thanks to you guys, my problem is solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
AdminRequestTime =  new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

A timespan doesn't have a format, it just contains the data to represent a timespan. The base unit there is ticks.

What you're asking is incompatible: you want a timespan, but you also want a specific format.

If what you're asking is how to format the current time of day in HH:mm, you can achieve that like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

If what you're asking is how to create a timespan that only has the hour and minute component, try this:

```
var x = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0);
Console.WriteLine(x); // Outputs 15:52:00
```